Android studio jump to declaration scrolls editor canvas
After a recent update to Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 2 I noticed strange editor behavior.
After I jump to a function declaration sometimes the editor canvas is scrolled to a cursor position at the function name, like this

So I have to scroll left each time, which is super inconvenient for me.
Does anyone know, that is a bug or a feature? Is there a way to disable that? I didn't find anything appropriate in the settings.

I notices that too. Probably a feature, but still really annoying.
